# ") was unexpected at this time. " after a search

Tags: arrays, batch-file, dos

----- Comments exist ONLY for this 'Request for Help' posting.
  Thank you for your consideration of this problem and help!

----------------- Overview
  An amateur & cumbersome implemenation of 'Search and Replace'
The line(s) contained within the input file, '2arc!XJ!.txt' are
searched for various substring(s), 'XSUBSTG'  When found the array
element(s), !ARY[%%j]!, containing the substring are flagged 'void'
so when the file is reformed at, 'Point B' the substring is omitted.

It's my recollection, been struggling with this for many weeks,
that prior to the inclusion of the block of code at, 'Point C' all
of the existing code was functional and error free.  When the block
of code at, 'Point C' was added, the ') was unexpected at this time.'
error occurred.

The only code above label ':TWO' is a few set statement to
initialize the variable(s), a FOR /F loop with it's matching
parenthesis, and a block code identical to the 'TWO' block, it
just searches for a different substring.

Currently, this snippet functions up to the deletion at, 'Point A'
that is when the, ') was unexpected at this time.' error occurs and
execution stops.

It's my hope that a solution can be found.  Secondly, if the
readers of this forum are so moved to advise me on how to improve
this code, and my overall coding ability, knowledge, let me thank
everyone, in advance.  Your help & advise is VERY much welcomed.

Please accompany any instruction(s), improvement(s) with simply,
detailed explanation(s) as knowledge and understanding is sorely
lacking.

Again, thank you one and all for your help!

```
 :TWO
            echo :  ------------------ Search: Two
            set XS2=1
            set XSTG=
 :TEST2
            If !XS2! GTR !XMAX! Goto LOOP
               FOR /L %%j in (%XS2%,1,%XMAX%) do (
                  set XSTG=!ARY[%%j]!
                  set XSUBSTG=!XSTG:~22,%X10%!
                  echo : --------- 10 Begin
                  echo :     XS2=  "!XS2!"
                  echo :     XSTG= "!XSTG!"
                  echo :     XSUBSTG= "!XSUBSTG!"
               call d:\bat\sleep 1
                  If [!XSUBSTG!]==[EOF--Disk:] Goto SKIP2
                     echo : 10 Included - B
                     echo :       ary= "!XSTG!"
                     Goto END
 :SKIP2
                     echo : 10 Skipped - B
                     set ARY[!XS2!]=void
                     set XSTG=!ARY[%XS2%]!
                     echo :     ary= "!XSTG!"
 :END
                     set /a XS2+=1
               )
               echo : --- End For10 -j
               Goto TEST2

 :LOOP
 :: -----  Point 'A'
         If EXIST !XDRV!!XPTHt!2arc!XJ!.txt del !XDRV!!XPTHt!2arc!XJ!.txt> NUL
 :: -----  Point 'B'
         FOR /L %%k in (1,1,%XMAX%) do (
             if !ARY[%%k]!==[void] Goto JUMP
                echo !ARY[%%k]!>> "!XDRV!!XPTHt!2arc!XJ!.txt"
 :JUMP
         )
         set ARY
         pause


 :: -----  Point 'C' - Start of Block
         cls
         echo :
         echo :      Compostion of 2arc!XJ!.txt
         echo :
         FOR /L %%m in (1,1,%XMAX%) do (
             set ARY[%%m]=
         )
         cls
         echo :
         echo :      Array after Flush / Reset
         echo :
         set ARY
         pause
 ::  -----  End of Block

         set /A XJ+=1
         Goto FILTER
```

Could NOT figure out how to attach a file so the debug output with the
") was unexpected at this time." error was inserted here.

```
 :  ------------------ Two
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "1"
 :     XSTG= "void"
 :     XSUBSTG= ""
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "void"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "2"
 :     XSTG= "    Atlanta 2960.txt                                                 2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "          "
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "    Atlanta 2960.txt                                                 2"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "3"
 :     XSTG= "    Boston 2961.txt                                                  2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "          "
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "    Boston 2961.txt                                                  2"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "4"
 :     XSTG= "    Cancun 29 62.txt                                                 2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "          "
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "    Cancun 29 62.txt                                                 2"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "5"
 :     XSTG= "    Denver 2963.txt                                                  2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "          "
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "    Denver 2963.txt                                                  2"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "6"
 :     XSTG= "    Eaton 265.txt                                                    2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "          "
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "    Eaton 265.txt                                                    2"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "7"
 :     XSTG= "    Glasgow 2 9 6 7.txt                                              2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "t         "
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "    Glasgow 2 9 6 7.txt                                              2"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "8"
 :     XSTG= "    Hartford 269.txt                                                 2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "          "
 : 10 Included - B
 :       ary= "    Hartford 269.txt                                                 2"
 : --- End For10 -j
 : --------- 10 Begin
 :     XS2=  "9"
 :     XSTG= "                      EOF--Disk:2  Sun 02/10/2013  ---               2"
 :     XSUBSTG= "EOF--Disk:"
 : 10 Skipped - B
 :     ary= "void"
 : --- End For10 -j
 ) was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: my best advice - break this down into (much) smaller pieces and debug them - for example, as you said, until code after 'C' was added, it worked - go back that far and see

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to set labels inside of blocks, they are not working as expected, as they break each loop.

And if the next line after the label begins with `)` you got your syntax error.

In your case it's the label `:JUMP` causing the error.
But like I said, the rest will neither work.